# Facebook Graph API to reply to a review on my Business page

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api

I have these permissions for my FB App.

```
`email`
`default`
`publish_pages`
`manage_pages`
```

I was able to fetch the reviews on my Business Page through the graph API. I am stuck in finding out how to reply to a review using the API. Suppose Person A reviewed my Business page and left a review. So I want to reply to Person As review through API.
I have tried the following but none of them is working.

CURL method:

```
$chu = curl_init();
curl_setopt($chu, CURLOPT_URL, "https://graph.facebook.com/v3.2/{fb_user_id}_{fb_comment_id}/comments?message=Thanks!!&access_token={access_token}");
curl_setopt($chu, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($chu, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($chu, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 50);
$resultu = curl_exec($chu);
curl_close($chu);
$resultu = json_decode($resultu);
echo "<pre>";
print_r($resultu);
```

Also I have tried Graph API method:

```
include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/manager/include/contact-header.php";
require_once CORE_PATH.'manager/all_apis/php-graph-sdk/src/Facebook/autoload.php';
$fb = new Facebook\Facebook([
    'app_id'                => FB_APP_ID,
    'app_secret'            => FB_APP_SECRET,
    'default_graph_version' => FB_APP_API_VERSION,
]);
try {
  $response = $fb->post(
    '/{fb_user_id}_{fb_comment_id}/comments', // user_id is the ID of the user who made the page
    array (
      'message' => 'This is a test comment',
    ),
    '{access_token}'
  );
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
  echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
  exit;
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
  echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
  exit;
}
$graphNode = $response->getGraphNode();
echo "<pre>";
print_r($graphNode);
```

None of the above is working. I get the following error.

```
stdClass Object
(
    [error] => stdClass Object
        (
            [message] => (#200) You do not have sufficient permissions to perform this action
            [type] => OAuthException
            [code] => 200
            [fbtrace_id] => HvneY0sxX69
        )

)
```

Can someone please guide me?

Comment: You must have enough permissions and your application must be validated by Facebook.

Comment: @KubiRoazhon all the above permissions I have mentioned has been approved by FB.

Comment: @KubiRoazhon is this correct `{fb_user_id}_{fb_comment_id}/comments`??

Comment: But when you see the message, it is clearly a question of permissions. I'm not seing the page Id in your query.

Comment: That is where I guess I am stuck. What else permission is required to post a reply to review? where exactly do I need to put the page ID?

Comment: @KubiRoazhon do we also need `user_posts` permission to reply to a review through API?

Comment: @KubiRoazhon I got it working. I forgot to add `publish_pages` in permissions array while asking for permission from users.

Comment: Can you plz tell me how did you get the reviews? I have tried many ways but could not found any reviews. Do i need to login to get the reviews?

Comment: @ManeeshRao inorder to use facebook graph API you must use have registered for app. Then you will get app id and app secret which you need to use in the SDK. Also as far as I know at a time you can only fetch 15 reviews max.

Comment: Thanks for the update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is because you use the User access_token. You need to use Page access token

**1. New client**

```
$fb = new Facebook\Facebook([
    'app_id'                => FB_APP_ID,
    'app_secret'            => FB_APP_SECRET,
    'default_graph_version' => FB_APP_API_VERSION,
]);
```

**2. Get access token**

```
$helper = $fb->getRedirectLoginHelper();
$accessToken = $helper->getAccessToken( 'your_callback_url' );

$oAuth2Client = $fb->getOAuth2Client();

if (! $accessToken->isLongLived()) {
    // Exchanges a short-lived access token for a long-lived one
    try {
       $accessToken = $oAuth2Client->getLongLivedAccessToken($accessToken);
    } catch (Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
       \\ Error message
    }
}

$facebook_oauth_token_value = $accessToken->getValue();
```

**3. Get /me**

```
// Build the request for the user 
$request = $fb->request("GET", "me");
$request->setAccessToken($facebook_oauth_token_value);
// Send request and store the response.
$response = $fb->getClient()->sendRequest($request);
// Fetch this user.
$body = $response->getDecodedBody();
```

**4. Get Pages AND access_token for each page**

```
// Build the request for the pages access tokens  
$request = $fb->request("GET", '/'.$body['id'].'/accounts?fields=name,access_token,id,link&access_token='.$facebook_oauth_token_value);
// Send request and store the response.
$response = $fb->getClient()->sendRequest($request);
// Fetch all the pages for this user.
$body = $response->getDecodedBody();
```

**5. If pages save each page access token**

```
if (is_array($body['data']) && count($body['data'])) {
    // do something with your pages (save data in database)
}
```

**6. Post reply**

```
// build the facebook POST request to post a reply to review.
$response = $fb->post('/' . $review_id.'/comments?',[
   'message' => $comment,
], $page_api_key);

$body = $response->getDecodedBody();
```